# Поиск окружности с помощью Emgu cv C#

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

не могли бы вы мне помочь. Я отфильтровал изображение, и вот результат.[image]

На исходном изображении точка красная.
Как мне отслеживать координаты этой точки?
Вот код отвечающий за фильтрацию изображения и поиск.

```
public PointF FindCircle(Bitmap img, out Bitmap imageHandle)
{
    img = img.Clone(Rectangle, img.PixelFormat);
    mainImage = new Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>(img);
    processedImage = mainImage.InRange(new Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr(ColorData.Lower.Blue, ColorData.Lower.Green, ColorData.Lower.Red), new Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr(ColorData.Upper.Blue, ColorData.Upper.Green, ColorData.Upper.Red));
    processedImage = processedImage.SmoothGaussian(9);
    Emgu.CV.Structure.CircleF[] circles = processedImage.HoughCircles(new Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray(ColorData.LowerGray), new Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray(ColorData.UpperGray), 2, processedImage.Height / 4, Main.main.GetMinRadius(), Main.main.GetMaxRadius()).SelectMany(u => u.Select(s => s)).ToArray();
    foreach (var c in circles)
    {
        Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.Circle(mainImage, new Point((int)c.Center.X, (int)c.Center.Y), 3, new Emgu.CV.Structure.MCvScalar(0, 255, 0), -1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.AntiAlias, 0);
        mainImage.Draw(c, new Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr(Color.Red), 3);
    }
    imageHandle = processedImage.Bitmap;
    return PointF.Empty;
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Эта точка на хорошо оформленную окружность никак не тянет, и метод Хафа вряд ли сможет правильно найти её центр.

В данном случае, если на реальном отфильтрованном изображении нет помех, то  достаточно найти максимум `cvMinMaxLoc` или центр масс `cvMoments`

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести пример кода? Не до конца разобрался с данной библиотекой.

Comment: Для цветного изображения  устанавливаете `cvSetImageCOI` в красный канал.  Вызываете [cvMinMaxLoc](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/bc8effe8-71d2-2817-3208-0d05d771e8b6.htm) для матрицы, после этого в `maxLoc` координаты максимума